# Can a integer array hold floating point numbers or characters?

Tags: arrays, c

Why in this code the integer array is able to hold floating point numbers and characters, I mean what is the real working of sprintf,  what is it(sprintf) actually doing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  int arr[20];
  int y=10;
  char c='A';
  float k=13.4;
  sprintf(arr,"%d %c %.1f",y,c,k);
  printf("%s",arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code currently has undefined behavior because of incompatible pointer types. You can fix that by replacing `arr` with `(char *)arr` in the calls to `sprintf` and `printf`. Although that is legal (because character types have some special properties that make it so), it is still bad coding practice. It is better to change `arr` to be an array of `char`, e.g. `char arr[80];`.

Comment: Why would you do this? Use structures. Using an int array for storing floats is like going to the pet shop when you want a cat, then ask for a dog, then ask how turn the dog into a cat. Just use the type you need from the start.

Comment: Also, after `sprintf` has filled the `int` array `arr` with some bytes, the `int` values will have implementation-defined values. In some (uncommon) implementations, they may be invalid `int` values ("trap representations") and an implementation-defined signal may be raised when the value is used in an expression.

Comment: Also, it is worth pointing out that the only thing the integer array is storing in this case is a sequence of characters generated by `sprintf`. The fact that floating point numbers and integers where passed as the variable arguments of the `sprintf` call is irrelevant (as long as the string generated by the `sprintf` call fits in the space provided by the first argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `sprintf` see of `arr` is simply a memory address, and it starts writing byte after byte there. Then `printf` takes the same address, assumes the bytes there are intended as a zero-terminated string and start printing it with that assumption.

It's NOT a good idea to do like this.

If you really want to study this, have a look at this source:

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/sprintf.c.html

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/iovsprintf.c.html#__vsprintf_internal